# Trying to store value of jquery callback, but code is running out of sequence

Tags: jquery

I have some code that does this:

```
function A(){
    $.ajax({
        ...blah blah...
        success: function(data){
            return data;
    });
 }
```

and then I'm trying to use the data later:

```
var x = A();
x.doSomething();
```

but x is never stored, since A() takes a while.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other Questions about the same topic:

- [Promote callback onSuccess return value to the Caller Function return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768457/promote-callback-onsuccess-return-value-to-the-caller-function-return-value)
- [How does one return data to the original caller function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094716/how-does-one-return-data-to-the-original-caller-function-in-javascript)

I'm sure there are more.  However the advice in all of them will boil down to two paths to take.

### Pass a callback down the line

```
function A(callback){
    $.ajax({
        //...blah blah...
        success: function(data){
          if (typeof callback == 'function') callback(data);
        }
    });
 }

 // passing our function through will cause it to be called after the data
 // is received
 A(function(data) {
  data.doSomething();
 });
```

### Making your AJAX Synchronous

This option seems easier, but it will also block **all script execution** while it waits for your AJAX request, and therefore is not as desireable

```
function A() {
  var retValue;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    success: function(data){ 
      retValue = data;
    }
  });
  return retValue;
}

var x = A();
x.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not manipulate data inside of the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Taking meder's answer and extending it:

Why not take action immediately on success, as in:

```
function A()
{
  $.ajax
  (
    {
      success: function(data)
      {
        data.doSomething();
      }
    }
  );
}
```